# Markov property of SDE's solution

Tags: probability, markov-process, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Considering the SDE $dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma (t,X_t)dW_t$ ($W$ is Brownian motion)

If there exists weak solution $(X,W),(\Omega ,\mathscr{F} ,P),\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$, is $X$ Markov process?

I know that if this SDE is well posed (i.e. for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, there exists unique weak solution whose initial value is $x$), $X$ holds Strong Markov property.

My question: When $X$ holds Markov property?

Comment: In general, weak existence does not imply the Markov property. There are, however, Markovian selection theorems which show that - under quite weak assumptions - it is possible to select for each initial value $x$ some (weak) solution $P_x$ such that $(X_t,P_x)$ is a Markov process (here $X$ is the canonical process); see e.g. Ethier + Kurtz for further details.

Comment: @saz Hi, I didn't find what you said in Eithier and Kurtz's book (Markov Processes Characterization and Convergence ). Would you like to detail a bit?

Comment: @NathanExplosion Take a look at Theorem 5.19 on p.210

Comment: @saz Thanks. So the (even strong) Markov property holds as long as the martingale problem is well-posed.